# ¿Cómo generar una vista donde una de las columnas pueda provenir de dos referencias?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, firebird

Tengo 3 tablas en una base de datos en Firebird:

```
TSERVICIOOFRECIDO(
    IFOLIO,
    VPERSONARFC,
    VSERVICIOCODIGO,
    VEMPLEADORFC,
    DASERVICIOFECHA,
    DESERVICIOHONORARIOS,
    VPAGADO
)
TFISICA(
    VFISICARFC,
    VFISICANOMBRE
)
TMORAL(
    VMORALRFC,
    VMORALRAZONSOCIAL
)
```

La tabla `TSERVICIOOFRECIDO` referencía tanto a `TFISICA` como a `TMORAL` en el campo `VPERSONARFC`

Quiero crear una Vista que donde pueda ver el nombre/razon social del cliente a según el valor del rfc, es decir, que busque el rfc en una de las tablas, y si no lo encuentra, lo busque en la otra, algo como:

```
CREATE VIEW VISTACLIENTE(NOMBRE_CLIENTE) AS SELECT TFISICA.VFISICANOMBRE OR 
TMORAL.VMORALRAZONSOCIAL FROM TSERVICIOOFRECIDO JOIN TFISICA ON 
TSERVICIOOFRECIDO.VPERSONARFC=TFISICA.VFISICARFC OR TSERVICIOOFRECIDO JOIN 
TMORAL ON TSERVICIOOFRECIDO.VPERSONARFC=TMORAL.VMORALRFC
```

No se si me estoy explicando bien

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar una condición [IIF](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-iif.html)

`CREATE VIEW VISTACLIENTE(NOMBRE_CLIENTE) AS`

`SELECT iif( TFISICA.VFISICANOMBRE = NULL, TMORAL.VMORALRAZONSOCIAL, TFISICA.VFISICANOMBRE )`

`FROM TSERVICIOOFRECIDO`

`LEFT JOIN TFISICA ON TSERVICIOOFRECIDO.VPERSONARFC=TFISICA.VFISICARFC`

`LEFT JOIN TMORAL ON TSERVICIOOFRECIDO.VPERSONARFC=TMORAL.VMORALRFC`

Y también debes usar LEFT JOIN para que ambas tablas referenciadas sean incluidas en la consulta, tengan o no tengan datos.

Comment: Esto resolvió el problema, muchas gracias. Solo un detalle, en "TFISICA.VFISICANOMBRE = NULL" no me funcionó tal cual usando Firebird 2.5, en lugar de eso utilicé "TFISICA.VFISICANOMBRE IS NULL" y problema resuelto, de igual manera gracias.